# Is it possible to modify or add my own colour themes?

Tags: settings

Under Settings > Theme, there is the option to choose an "Accent colour" - is it possible to alter any of the elements in this list? I see that there is an "htc" option on my phone that is almost identical to the green theme, but the "nokia blue" on my wife's phone seems a lot nicer (although that may just be the Nokia's screen being nicer).

Is there any way to personalise these colours at all (even if it requires a developer unlocked device)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I do this all the time. It does require your phone to be unlocked. The easiest way is to install the [Advanced Configuration Tool](http://www.xda-developers.com/windows_phone/windows-phone-7-advanced-configuration-tool/). [More details here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1361454). I can't find a working URL right now, but search around on the XDA forums  and Google. You might get lucky.

All that app does is modify the correct registry settings. So if you can't find the tool, get a registry editor for your phone and hunt around the XDA forums for `windows phone 7 accent color registry values`.

If I remember correctly, you can't add new colors. You are forced to change an existing one.

**Backup your phone first** I would hate to see you with a bricked phone!

ps. the Nokia Blue color is #004C9A